# SwiftUI + Firestore - Cannot create user in firestore after authenticating

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

My intended flow is that someone reaches the signup page, enters their email and password, then when it is successfully processed then create a user in Firestone. After a lot of print lines, I can see the authentication part works just fine, but when I try to create the user in firestore it crashes. I suspect it's an async issue because I try to write the below code, but currUser?.uid is nil. Please help!

```
db.collection("users").document(currUser?.uid ?? "").setData(user) { err in
```

This is also how I'm trying to combat the async issue. The below is the code for the sign up button

```
            Button(action: {
                self.signUp()
                self.viewModel.createUser()
            })
```

I've also attached the error I am getting below:

2020-06-21 23:28:20.163164-0400 Routines[5662:144417] *** Assertion failure in firebase::firestore::api::DocumentReference::DocumentReference(model::ResourcePath, std::shared_ptr)(), /Users/paulachan/Documents/Apps/Routines/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/api/document_reference.cc:67
2020-06-21 23:28:20.241127-0400 Routines[5662:144417] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that `currUser` is null, so `db.collection("users").document(currUser?.uid ?? "")` evaluates to `db.collection("users").document("")` which is invalid.

Based on the code you shared we can't say why `currUser` is null, but it typically means that you're trying to access `Auth.auth().currentUser` before it is initialized. I'd recommend using the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) as it ensures your code only executes once the user sign in is completed:

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  if (user != nil) {
    db.collection("users").document(user?.uid ?? "").setData(user) { err in
      ...
    }
  }
}
```